# Delete the entire content of all table in a Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 8 tables in mysql database. In "teacher" and "student table" i have  teacher_id column. I want to delete the entire data of all table from database but only those data were remains in table which have column named teacher_id and whose value is = 1

Thanks

Comment: How do you delete the data? How can there be anything left?

Comment: delete * from table x

Answer (score 2):

`DELETE FROM sometable WHERE teacher_id != 1;`

Comment: Thanks, but i want to delete all content of all table whose teacher_id !=1 in a single Query

Comment: SQL doesn't support deleting from all tables in a single query. If you *really* need to do that--and you surely don't--write a stored procedure.

Comment: How does that match the question "Delete the entire content of all table in a database"?

Comment: I think it can be done with using cascading delete but i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

To empty a SQL table use:

```
TRUNCATE table_name;
```

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html

To empty a whole database, it is often faster to drop the database and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

To delete data from a table using no in operators. This code should be used.

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE teacher_id <> 1;
```

Comment: thanks but the problem is that i have 2 table and i want to delete all rows of both table except those row whose column i.e teacher_id=1

Comment: Well it can be done by using   
    DELETE teacher, student FROM teacher LEFT JOIN student  ON teacher.teacher_id = student.teacher_id where teacher.teacher_id !=1